# Get element in position N if exists

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to get a list of DIVS;

```
var $items = $this.children("div.poster");
```

How can I get the element in position 4 from $items if it exists?

Comment: $this.children("div.poster")[3]

Comment: And if I have an item can I find its position in $items? I need to do both ways. I was looking at index() but not sure if that is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.eq()` method:

```
var $item4 = $items.eq(3);
```

To get the position of an item, use `.index()`

```
var position = $item4.index($items);
```